# If html/css based questions is allowed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, questions, migration

Today I saw a question [Why are people making tables with divs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277778/why-are-people-making-tables-with-divs) Which have no linked with any programming language (including client side javascript or others). It is pure HTML/CSS based question.

I wonder if it suited at UX site not Programmers? But it get lot of upvotes and answers so I assuming it allowed under some criteria. What could be the criteria of allowing this question?

Comment: regarding more than usual upvotes, these are because question is currently in hot list, see eg [Prevent questions on Hot List from being upvoted by casual visitors (only rep is from association bonus)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238420/165773)

Comment: @gnat I have no issue with high votes as users having more specialization in HTML/css are better to understand quality of this question and related answers. My point is if it suited to programmer stack exchange at all ?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a UX question.

The question is not asking about the UX of tables, but why data is laid out in what looks like tables but doesn't actually use the `<table>` structure.

Comment: Well I think still better suited to UX instead of programmers as question deals with table vs div with display:table attitude. Which is more suitable there. Is not a programmers site should deals only directly/undirectly programming related questions ?

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj - UX is not concerned with how you code up your page/form to display your data, but with what structure you use to display the data. So UX will be involved in the decision to use a table, but not how you actually code up that table.